# Pawn exchanges in e4&d4 openings

Tags: learning

I'm just learning.  I'm at a loss to deal with the opening razzamatazz where white's pawns are at the centre and under attack by Black's pawns & knights-does one defend the pawns by bringing in the heavy pieces or just cede the center? I think this is a question answered by exchange theory but I cannot find a suitable and comforting answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "opening razzamatazz" and "exchange theory"? These just seem to be terms that you made up yourself, and it makes it virtually impossible to understand what it is that you're actually after since the community cannot read your mind. If you have difficulties articulating what your problem is, it could be helpful to include an example position that highlights what you're wondering about.

Answer (score 1):

One should not cede the center without receiving other valuable advantages. Giving more specific advice is difficult.  Center control is a continuum from classical to modern & hypermodern ideas. Action depends on the position, your style & opening, and the opponent's responses. Amateurs, like myself, tend to make too many pawn moves in the opening. Pay attention to development.